# Filter annotate When Case with foregin key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

i have 2 models:

```
class ServiceRequest(models.Model):
    post_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    service = models.IntegerField(default=102)

class RequestSession(models.Model):
    request = models.ForeignKey(ServiceRequest)
    post_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

If `service` have value `102`, it will have one or more `RequestSession`.

I have queryset get all `ServiceRequest` : `ServiceRequest.objects.all()`

My question is : How to `order_by`  `post_time` if `service!=102`. If `service=102` i want order by greatest `post_time` of `requestsession_set`?

i tried `annotate` but i dont know how to get greatest `post_time` in `requestsession` inside When then

My query i tried:

`queryset.annotate(time_filter=Case(
                        When(service_id=102, then=('requestsession_set__post_time')),
                        default=Value('post_time'),
                        output_field=DateTimeField(), ), ).order_by("-time_filter")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
When(service=102, then=Max('requestsession_set__post_time')),
```

Notice that I have also replaced `service_id` for `service` since `service` is simply an `IntegerField` in your example.

Also, it should be `default='post_time'`, without `Value`. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#value-expressions

Comment: change `then=Max('requestsession_set__post_time')` to `then=Max('requestsession__post_time')` and it work. Django said `requestsession_set` is not field accepted